# default webform using and namespace queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When creating webform in VS 2013, the codebehind contains several using alias but when I save the page all the using alias are removed. Only one using `using System;` is kept. Why is it so?

Also the code behind has namespace, when I see different web pages tutorials they simply start with `public partial class`. What is the difference ? Should I simply remove the namespace, does it effect my webpages ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Sample.UI.pages
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you right click on the project and select properties what is the default namespace ? also try starting vs2013 as administrator

Comment: the default namespace is Sample.UI

Answer (score 1):

1) If you aren't adding any extra code that would be accessible via a using statement, then you don't need any extra using statements.

2) public partial class refers to the fact that the class is split over 3 files. One is the aspx file, the designer.cs file, and the aspx.cs code behind. Do not remove any namespaces unless you know what you're doing. The CLR uses the assemblies namespaces to find code to execute.